# How do I export database tables data from hdfs into local csv using hive without write permission

Tags: hive, hiveql

I dont have write permission on hdfs cluster.
I am accessing database tables created/stored on hdfs using hive via edge node.
I have read access.
I want to export data from tables located on hdfs into csv on my local system.
How should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert overwrite local directory '/____/____/' row format delimited fields terminated by ',' select * from table;
```

Note that this may create multiple files and you may want to concatenate them on the client side after it's done exporting.

Comment: Will this work without write access to hdfs, as I have to perform these operations on cluster

Comment: @Tilo No, you can not because you don't have permission to write on the cluster